# Counting the number of ways to partition N integers to N/3 triples

Tags: combinatorics

I am interested in counting the number of ways of partitioning N integers (N is a multiple of 3) to N/3 triples. I came up with this formula for which I am looking for a closed form or tight asymptotic upper-bound:

$C = \prod_{j=0}^{j=(N-3)/3}  \binom{N-3j}{3} 
$

Trivial upper-bound is $N^N$. I am looking for tight upper-bound.

Comment: Your formula assumes you care about the order you choose the triples in.  Is that correct?  If $N=6$, is choosing $\{1,2,3\}$ then $\{4,5,6\}$ different from choosing $\{4,5,6\}$ and then $\{1,2,3\}$.  If you don't care about the order you need to divide by $(\frac N3)!$

Comment: @RossMillikan  No. I don't care about the order.

Comment: @RossMillikan Please post your answer.

Comment: You should update your formulas to use $N$ instead of $n$ as in the start of the post.  It is more convenient to use the number of triples and a couple answers have used $n$ for $\frac N3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $n=\frac N3$ as the number of triplets.  If you don't care about the order the triplets are selected, the number of ways is $$\frac {(3n)!}{(3!)^nn!}$$
You can get this by permuting the numbers in one of $(3n)!$ ways and taking the first three as the first triplet, the next three as the next triplet, and so on.  We don't care about the order of the three in each triplet, which gives us $n$ divisions by $3!$.  We also don't care about the order of the triplets, so we divide by $n!$  Applying Stirling's approximation to the large factorials we get
$$\frac {(3n)!}{(3!)^nn!}\approx \frac {(3n)^{3n}e^n\sqrt{2\pi3n}}{e^{3n}6^nn^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}=\sqrt 3\frac{n^{2n}27^n}{e^{2n}6^n}\approx \sqrt 3\ \cdot0.609^nn^{2n}$$

Comment: Thank you. Perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

Denoting the number of triples as $n$ one obtains:
$$
C=\frac{(3n)!}{n!(3!)^n}.
$$
Then apply [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to obtain $C\sim\sqrt{3}\left(\frac{9n^2}{2e^2}\right)^n$.

Comment: can you explain the derivation of your answer?

Comment: The simple derivation is to imagine lining up the $3n$ numbers, which you can do in $(3n)!$ ways.  The first three are the first triplet, the next three the second, and so on.  Within each triplet you don't care about the order of the numbers, so you need to divide by $3!$ for each triplet, which gives the denominator.  As with my comment to the question, this assumes you care about the order the triplets are chosen.  Otherwise you should divide by $n!$

Comment: I corrected the answer for the case when the order of triples does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer should be $$\frac{N!}{(3!)^{N/3}}$$

I got this by just simply expanding the product of binomial coefficients